# Safely replacing text with m4, disabling new defines

Tags: m4

Given a "rules" file and an "input" file, I would like to process the input file with m4 using the rules defined in the rule file.

So, for example, if the rule file contains

```
define(FOO, BAR)dnl
```

and the text file contains

```
FOO FOO define(FOO,BAZ) BAR
```

I would like to get

```
BAR BAR define(BAR,BAZ) BAR
```

instead of the expected

```
BAR BAR  BAZ
```

I would like to use a file to define the macros, and process the other file skipping any new define or change in the m4 behavior. Macros should just be expanded, never altered.

Basically, this is because in the text file there may be some text which looks like M4 code, but it is not, and I which it to be ignored.

Or, from another perspective, I need something like search-and-replace, but with the ability to define "complex" macros with arguments.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use -P flag.

> -P, --prefix-builtins 
>   force a `m4_' prefix to all builtins

rules.m4:

```
m4_define(FOO, BAR)m4_dnl
```

text.data:

```
FOO FOO define(FOO,BAZ) BAR
```

The results is:

```
$ make -P rules.m4 text.data
BAR BAR define(BAR,BAZ) BAR
```

### Update 1

You could undefine the m4_define macro altogether. That should be the last line of the rules.m4 file.

```
m4_undefine(`m4_define')
```

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of it, but it doesn't really solve the problem: what if the text contains both `m4_define()` and `define()`? After looking around, I concluded that probably there's no simple solution to my answer.

Comment: You can undefine m4_define macro.

Comment: Can I undefine all the other commands, too? undefine(\`undefine')? And what about the quotations? The `define`, in my case, was an example, but the point is to prevent the "behavior" to change, but allowing macro expansions in the processed file.

Comment: Sounds like a contradiction to me. A macro expansion is a change. If there is no change, there is no macro expansion.

Comment: This is why I was talking about two different files: a rule file (rules -> not changing) and input file (to be changed), but I don't want that the content of the input file changes the rules that are applied to it.

Comment: But m4 does not work this way. Maybe you should consider simple string substitution.